# How to mix onehotencoding and bagofword

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking for a model, a sort of **onehotencoding**, that could mix columns of the same category in a single vector.

- Having the Data `[5,8,1,3]`
- it will gives me :    `[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]`

with an arbitrary size set at 12.

I looked at **bagofword** but I did not find how to set the vector size independently of the input data.

If somebody can gives me some clues, it will be find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `np.zeros` and than set value `1` to the indices from your `data` list:

```
z = np.zeros(12)
data = [5,8,1,3]
z[data] = 1
print(z)
```

output:

```
[0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that [Bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) models are used when dealing with `text`. For this simpler task you can just use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) and specify a `minlength`:

```
l = [5,8,1,3]

np.bincount(l, minlength=12)
# array([0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
```